# Converting Javascript to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, web-deployment

How can i convert this programme to only php with the calculations in there without using the JavaScript? I'm using echo " "; Should i use a If compute($choice)

```
<html>
     <head><title>hw4-5</title>
      <style type='text/css'>
     table{color:black;background-color:lightgray;border:6px solid black;border-width:4px;}
     th{color:white;background-color:black;outline-style:solid;outline-width:2px;border:2px solid black;}
     input.button{color:black;background-color:red;border:4px solid black;}
     input#idname1,input#idname2,input#idname3{background-color:DEDEE6;border:4px solid black;}
    </style>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    function compute(choice)
    {
     var tbox1=document.getElementById('idname1');
     var tbox2=document.getElementById('idname2');
     var tbox3=document.getElementById('idname3');
     if(choice==1){tbox2.value=parseInt(tbox1.value)*(tbox1.value);}
     else if(choice==2){tbox3.value=parseInt(tbox1.value)*4;}
     else if(choice==3){tbox2.value=parseInt(tbox1.value)*(tbox1.value);
     tbox3.value=parseInt(tbox1.value)*4;}
     else{tbox1.value=tbox2.value=tbox3.value='';}
      }
      </script>
    </head>
    <form>
   <table>
   <th colspan='2' >SQUARE PROBLEM</th>
   <tr><td><label>Side:     </label></td><td><input type='text' id='idname1' /></td></tr>
   <tr><td><label>Area:     </label></td><td><input type='text' id='idname2' /></td></tr>
   <tr><td><label>Perimeter:</label></td><td><input type='text' id='idname3' /></td></tr>
   <tr><td colspan='2' >
   <input class='button' type='button' value='Area'         onClick='compute(1)' />
    <input class='button' type='button' value='Perimeter' onClick='compute(2)' />
    <input class='button' type='button' value='Both'        onClick='compute(3)' />
    <input class='button' type='button' value='Clear'       onClick='compute(4)' /></td></tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

**PHP** Can not perform **client side operations** which this program is performing, hence you cannot convert this to PHP to be a substitute for JavaScript; hence any number of attempts are going to be useless.

**EDIT**

However you can post your values to a PHP page and do server side processing and show results on that next page.

Comment: Why not ajax? Calculation would be done in php, and events would be dealt with JS. Extra http requests for such situation would be overkill, but hey, that's what OP asked

Comment: @DamienPirsy That's true, but when the OP doesn't even want JavaScript in there then AJAX is out of question I assume. Since OP said `only php with the calculations in there without using the JavaScript`

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to convert it totally to PHP? then you can do it

```
     <?php 
       if(isset($_POST) && $_POST['submitbtn']!=''){
        $tbox1 = $_POST['idname1'];
        $tbox2 = $_POST['idname2'];
        $tbox3 = $_POST['idname3'];
        if($_POST['submitbtn'] =='Area'){$tbox2 = $tbox1*$tbox1;}
        if($_POST['submitbtn'] =='Perimeter'){$tbox3 = $tbox1*4;}
        if($_POST['submitbtn'] =='Both'){$tbox2 = $tbox1*$tbox1;$tbox3 = $tbox1*4;}
       } 
     ?>

    <form action="" method="post">
   <table>
   <tr><th colspan='2' >SQUARE PROBLEM</th></tr>
   <tr><td><label>Side:     </label></td><td><input type='text' id='idname1' name="idname1" value="<?php echo $tbox1?>" /></td></tr>
   <tr><td><label>Area:     </label></td><td><input type='text' id='idname2' name="idname2" value="<?php echo $tbox2?>" /></td></tr>
   <tr><td><label>Perimeter:</label></td><td><input type='text' id='idname3' name="idname3" value="<?php echo $tbox3?>" /></td></tr>
   <tr><td colspan='2'>
   <input class='button'  value='Area'   name="submitbtn"      type="submit" />
    <input class='button' value='Perimeter'  name="submitbtn"  type="submit" />
    <input class='button' value='Both'       name="submitbtn" type="submit" />
    <input class='button' value='Clear' name="clearbtn"  type="reset" /></td></tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Code with slight change. Just tried to replicate exact behavior of "with js"!

```
<html>
     <head><title>hw4-5</title>
      <style type='text/css'>
     table{color:black;background-color:lightgray;border:6px solid black;border-width:4px;}
     th{color:white;background-color:black;outline-style:solid;outline-width:2px;border:2px solid black;}
     input.button{color:black;background-color:red;border:4px solid black;}
     input#idname1,input#idname2,input#idname3{background-color:DEDEE6;border:4px solid black;}
    </style>
<?php 
$idname1 = "";
$answerA=0;
$answerP=0;

if (isset($_POST['butt1'])) {
    $idname1 = $_POST['idname1'];
    if($_POST['butt1']=="Area"){$answerA=$_POST['idname1'] * $_POST['idname1'];}
    else if($_POST['butt1']=="Perimeter"){$answerP=$_POST['idname1']*4;}
    else if($_POST['butt1']=="Both"){$answerA=$_POST['idname1'] * $_POST['idname1'];$answerP=$_POST['idname1']*4;}
    else{$answerA = $answerP = $idname1="";}
    }
?>

    </head>
    <form method="post">
   <table>
   <th colspan='2' >SQUARE PROBLEM</th>
   <tr><td><label>Side:     </label></td><td><input type='text' id='idname1' name="idname1" value="<?php echo($idname1); ?>"/></td></tr>
   <tr><td><label>Area:     </label></td><td><input type='text' id='idname2' name="idname2" value="<?php echo($answerA); ?>"/></td></tr>
   <tr><td><label>Perimeter:</label></td><td><input type='text' id='idname3' name="idname3" value="<?php echo($answerP); ?>"/></td></tr>
   <tr><td colspan='2' >
   <input class='button' type='submit' value='Area'  name="butt1"  />
    <input class='button' type='submit' value='Perimeter' name="butt1" />
    <input class='button' type='submit' value='Both' name="butt1"/>
    <input class='button' type='submit' value='Clear' name="butt1"/></td></tr>
    </table>

    </form>
    </html>
```